# How can I Loop through a dataframe with Dplyr and use mutate to change values of some cells based on a condition?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am writing a report using Rmarkdown, I have a data frame like this:

[image]

I want to check all cells and change the markup so the values that are smaller than "0.05" are highlighted in red. I managed to do that in a simpler data frame with only 2 rows and a specific cell, so it was easy and it's working. But in this case, I need to check all cells and I have no idea how to do it. I have tried with mutate_if, mutate_all and got nowhere.

This line was all that I needed to make it work on the other data frame:

```
mutate(p.value = cell_spec(p.value, "html", color = ifelse(p.value[1] < 0.05, "red", "black")))
```

Edit: as requested..

I am using Kable and KableExtra to do some of the printing on the report. Here is a code example that I used to do the highlighting on a more basic data frame:

```
aov.formiga <- aov(as.formula(sprintf("%s ~ Local", v)), formigas)
  d <- tidy(aov.formiga)
    print(
      d %>%
        replace(is.na(.),"") %>%
        mutate(p.value = cell_spec(p.value, "html", color = ifelse(p.value[1] < 0.05, "red", "black"))) %>%
        kable(format = "html", escape = F, col.names = c("Source", "DF","Anova SS", "Mean Square", "F Value", "Pr > F")) %>%
        kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"), full_width = F)
      )
```

That is the result of this print:

[image]

I can provide any data, but I can try to simplify the idea:

```
DF 
... A B C
1   1 2 1
2   2 1 2
3   3 4 1
```

Let's say I want to loop this DF and replace all 1 for "One" and leave the other values intact. If I can manage to do that with Dplyr I think I can work the other parts. Thank you!

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example

Comment: *"highlighted in red"* has nothing to do with `dplyr`. Please be clear in what you have (reproducible sample data) and what you are using (reproducible code including listing non-base packages).

Comment: Use `mutate_all` instead of `mutate`. See `?mutate_all` for examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your example data, if you want to turn all the cells greater than or equal to 2 to red:

```
x = c(A = 1, B = 2, C = 1)
y = c(A = 2, B = 1, C = 2)
z = c(A = 3, B = 4, C = 1) 
data=data.frame(rbind(x,y,z))

library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
    mutate_all(~cell_spec(.x, color = ifelse(.x >= 2, "red"," black"))) %>%
    kable(escape = F) %>%
    kable_styling()
```

[image]

**Response to comment**

The `ifelse()` breaks with `NA` values, so we can use `case_when()`:

```
data %>% 
    mutate_all(~cell_spec(.x, color = case_when(.x >= 2 ~ "red",
                                                TRUE ~ "black"))) %>%
    kable(escape = F) %>%
    kable_styling()
```

[image]

Comment: That is amazing. It is exactly what I needed. But in my case since the diagonal of my DF is all "NA", how can I skip the "NA"s on the  ifelse eval ? I got this error message:  `Error in if (substr(color, 1, 1) != "#" | nchar(color) != 9) return(color) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Calls: <Anonymous> ... cell_spec_html -> paste0 -> html_color -> sapply -> lapply -> FUN
Execution halted`

Comment: `Error in ifelse(.x < 0.05 ~ "red", TRUE ~ " black") : 
  'pairlist' object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... ~ -> .Call -> cell_spec -> cell_spec_html -> ifelse
Execution halted` .. maybe my NA's are in fact characters  "NA" and failing the "TRUE" eval ?

Comment: Looks like you've still got `ifelse` there.  Can you try changing that to `case_when()`?

Comment: Sorry! My bad! I didn't alter correctly! That's it, works amazingly. Thank you so much. Sorry to bother you for just one more thing, could you "guide me" through the code? Particularly what `~cell_spec` does, and why the `case_when` works with the NA's. Thank you again!

Comment: No problem, happy to help. `cell_spec()` specifies a format for the cell in the kable table, and if you look at the documentation for it, you'll see other options in addition to the text color. If you run the code only through the `mutate_all()` line, you'll get some html outputs in your console. `mutate_all()` adds a cell specification to every column. `case_when()` is a `dplyr` function that lets you avoid having to write nested `ifelse()` statements. If we used `ifelse()`, it would have been `color = ifelse(is.na(.x), "black", ifelse(.x >= 2, "red", "black"))`, which is less readable.

Comment: That's the first time I used this ".x" notation, so it would be possible to use another mutate_all call to format all cells to 5 decimal places with "format" using that same notation?

Comment: No need, you can just do `data %>% round(5) %>% mutate_all(~cell_spec(....`

Comment: Since I am working with p-values I can't round up. So I managed to do it with `mutate_if(is.numeric, format, digits=4,nsmall = 0) %>%` .. Thank you for your patience and goodwill to teach me so much today.